# Please explain me this function inidat

Tags: c, variables

What does that * means before u, what kind of the variable it is, and what will be the output of this function. 
Thanks

```
void inidat (int nx, int ny, float* u)
{
    int ix, iy;

    for (ix = 0; ix <= nx-1; ix++)
    {
        for (iy = 0; iy <= ny-1; iy++)
        {
            *(u+ix*ny+iy) = (float)(ix * (nx - ix - 1) * iy * (ny - iy - 1));
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pointer. A pointer is an object whose value refers to another value stored elsewhere in the computer memory using its address. A pointer references a location, and one can get the object stored at that location by "dereferencing" the pointer.

```
float * x; 
cout << *x;
cout << x;
```

To get the value of the pointer, you do the 2nd line.
To get the location of the pointer you do the 3rd line.

Answer (score 0):

`*` means that the follow variable is defined or used (to be used, as in this case, it must've been defined before) as a pointer.

As for the output of the function: it's `void` so it won't return any value but change some in the last line, I would need the context of the function to see what it's actually doing.